# Вывести с галереи изображение в ImageView

Tags: java, android, gallery

Хочу сделать так: нажимаешь на кнопку, открывается галерея, выбираешь картинку и она отображается в программе в ImageView. Картинка выбирается все работает только отображается ничего, просто пустая область.

```
//upload photo
        uploadPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1234;
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 
            switch(requestCode) { 
                case 1234:
                    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        ImageView photoRegistration = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testSet);
                        photoRegistration.setImageURI(selectedImage);

                    }
            }
    }
```

**xml:**

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/testSet"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_light" />
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20load%20image%20from%20gallery%20to%20imageview&es_th=1

Answer (score 1):

Вот так

```
final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                            final Bitmap selectedImages = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                            imageView2.setImageBitmap(selectedImages);
```